# Form To Two Different PHP Files

Tags: php, forms, intranet

I need to get a form to submit to two different PHP files in order to display information in two different ways. I am creating a company intranet and am working on the contacts page right now. I have the form currently set up as a nested form to show what I am trying to do (I do know that it wont work that way).

This is what I have right now.

```
<body style="background-color: #000000">
<form action="library/submit_corporate.php" method="post">
<form action="library/show_all_corporate.php" method="post">

<hr style="border: 1px solid #FFB25F"/>
<label>


<h3>Find A Corporate Contact</h3>
<br>
<table style="margin: auto;">
<tr>
<td style="color: #FF8500">
    Contact Name:
</td>
<td>        <input name="customer" id="C" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
</td>
<td id="C"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #FF8500"> OR FIND BY: </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: #FF8500">
    Business Name:
</td>
<td>        <input name="business" id="B" type="text" style="width: 200px" />
</td>
<td id="B"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp; </td>
<td><input type="submit" name="findThem" value="Find" class="submit" /></td>
</tr>

</table>
</label>
</form>
</form>
```

This is how I'm trying to access it from the first action PHP file:

```
        $name = $_POST['customer'];
        $business = $_POST['business'];

        include ("dbcon.php");
        fopen ("dbcon.php", "r");
        $result = mysqli_query($connect,"Select * FROM customers WHERE Business = '$name' OR Name = '$name' ");
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "Contact's Name: ".$row['Name'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Business Name: ".$row['Business'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Phone Number: ".$row['PhoneNum'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Email: ".$row['Email'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "Service: ".$row['Service'];
            echo "<br>";
            echo "<br>";

        }
?>
<table>
<tr>
<td><p>Do you want to see more about the contact?</p></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><form method="link" action="show_all_corporate.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Yes" class="submit"/>
    </form>
</td>
<td><form method="link" action="http://example.com/index.php">
    <input type="submit" value="No" class="submit"/>
    </form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I would appreciate any help I can get...

Comment: I'd love to work at your place to inject dem sqls all day long.

Comment: What about a radio to choose the display type you want before submitting to one script that will handle the radio choice in order to display the way the user wanted?

Comment: what's with the `fopen()` call? You've already `include()`d it...

Comment: Since the second form is shown to the user after submitting the first, you can trigger the second submit on the second page, just use hidden inputs and when the user submits to view the page, then it will trigger the second post.

Comment: The fopen() call was a safety because I have had the include() call act up on me before. The radio button suggestion wouldn't work, because what I am trying to do is to have the form be submitted and show a certain amount of information before asking if you want to see the rest of the information (I'm doing it this way as a way to give a bit of security to the contacts in the system). As for the hidden input to submit, how would one go about that?